Google Cloud Run Function not processing incoming requests separately
I am new to Google Cloud Run and also not a professional engineer, so I am grateful for any patience. I have:

Multiple Google Sheets with hundreds of rows of data
A Google Apps Script in each Google Sheet that: is triggered when an edit is made to the Sheet, creates an object of edited row data, and sends the object to a Cloud Run service via a POST request to the Cloud Run service
An HTTP Cloud Run service/Node app that receives the object, transforms the object's format, and sends the output to a CMS via REST API

There is a need to edit multiple rows, even dozens, at once and send them to be processed in the Cloud Run service.
Editing one row of data in the Sheet works fine. The output in the console, which includes the primary cell in the row as plain text followed by the object, is something like:
Bureau of Licensure: {"id":1234,"name":"Bureau of Licensure"}

Editing multiple rows of data in the Sheet at once does not process correctly. The result is something like (note that the objects are all the same, even though each row in the Sheet has its own different ID and name values):
Bureau of Licensure: {"id":1234,"name":"Bureau of Licensure"}
Board of Review: {"id":1234,"name":"Bureau of Licensure"}
Institute of Data: {"id":1234,"name":"Bureau of Licensure"}
Board of Accreditation: {"id":1234,"name":"Bureau of Licensure"}

Based on console logging in the Cloud Run Service, When multiple rows are changed, the Sheet does not appear to send every row's data in a single object. Rather, it appears a separate object is sent for each.
This is a representation of the code in the Cloud Run Service:
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
   if (req.method === 'POST') {
      let body = '';

      // Listen for data events to collect chunks of data
      req.on('data', chunk => {
         body += chunk.toString(); // Convert buffer to string
      });

      // Listen for the end event to process the complete data
      req.on('end', () => {
         console.log("Received POST data:", body)

.....assemble the body into an object.....

         // Get some metadata from an existing CMS page created for the row data
         documentBody = '';
         function getDocument() {
            return new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) {
               fetch(url, {
                  method: 'GET',
                  headers: {
                     authorization: token,
                     accept: "application/json",
                     contentType: "application/json"
                  }
               })
                  .then((res) => {
                     return res.json()
                  })
                  .then((jsonResponse) => {
                     documentBody = jsonResponse.content
                  })
                  .catch((err) => {
                     // handle error
                     console.error(err);
                  });
               resolve(res);
            });
         }

         // Send content object to Paligo
         function updateDocument() {
            return new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) {
               var data = {
                  "content": finalContent
               }
               var payload = JSON.stringify(data);
               fetch(url, {
                  method: 'PUT',
                  headers: {
                     authorization: token,
                     accept: "application/json",
                     contentType: "application/xml"
                  },
                  body: payload
               }).then(res => res.json())
                  .then(res => {
                  })
                  .catch((err) => {
                     // handle error
                     console.error(err);
                  });
               resolve(res);
            });
         }

         async function main() {
            await getDocument(res);
            await updateDocument(res);
         }
         main()

         // Send a response
         res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
         res.end(JSON.stringify({ message: 'Data received successfully!' }));
      });
   } else {
      res.writeHead(404, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
      res.end('Not Found');
   }
});
server.listen(8080, () => {
   console.log('Server running at http://localhost:8080/');
});

For reference, the Google Apps Script code resembles this:
spreadSheetName = "Sources"
numberOfColumns = 8
function atEdit(e) {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = s.getActiveRange();

  for (var i = 1; i <= range.getNumRows(); i++) {
    var r = range.getCell(i, 1)
    var row = r.getRow();
    var headerRow = s.getRange(1, 1, 1, numberOfColumns).getValues()
    var editedRow = s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numberOfColumns).getValues()

    // Unite header row and edited row into key values in a JSON file
    var r = {},
      i,
      keys = headerRow[0],
      values = editedRow[0];

    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
      r[keys[i]] = values[i];
    }

    function sendToCloudRun() {
      var data = {
        r
      }
      var payload = JSON.stringify(data);

      // Request sent to the Google Cloud Run Service
      var url = "<URL to CLOUD SERVICE>"
      var params = {
        headers: {
          accept: "application/json",
          contentType: "application/json"
        },
        method: "post",
        payload: payload,
      };
      var requestResult = UrlFetchApp.getRequest(url, params);
      var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
      console.log("response to send object: " + res.getContentText());
    }
    sendToCloudRun()
  }
}

It seems that the Cloud Run Service is not processing each row separately but somehow intermixing variables, producing an incorrect output.
I tried changing the max concurrency to 1 but that did not change the output.
Thank you for any insights or help.

I think you have a race condition when you process your row. They are all sent to Cloud Run, but processed in random order, maybe on several instances, with different latency,... Anyway, if your processing is not idempotent, you can't have a predictable output. You should group, in a same object, all the changes and send them in bulk to Cloud Run.

In addition to Guillaume's feedback, your Apps Script code has some issues. Have you defined an atEdit event or are you using the built-in onEdit? The onEdit (sic.) event captures the event data (e) but your code ignores this. onEdit will be fired for every change on the sheet when you really want a mechanism to capture the addition of a  row. There is an onChange trigger that can be used to determine the addition of one row but, without more work, I think you'll be challenged to automatically detect the addition of multiple rows and submit the batch to Cloud Run.

From the function name atEdit and your script, I guessed that you might install the OnEdit trigger to atEdit and you might want to directly run the script. Is my understanding correct? About the modification point, although I'm not sure about the specification of your API in your Node.js script, about your Google Apps Script, how about posting all values by one call of UrlFetchApp.fetch instead of it being used in a loop? Also, in order to correctly work the script under continuously editing the cells, how about using LockService?

@DazWilkin Thank you for your input. I am using onEdit but had renamed it to atEdit to fix an issue I caused. Thank you for pointing out the issues in the code

@guillaumeblaquiere Thank you I will attempt to go the route you suggested

@Tanaike Your comment makes a lot of sense, I will try those ideas. Thank you
